# getElementById() .innerHTML/.src

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a simple javascript game for college and am having trouble getting what i want to display on screen.

my script is as follows:

```
var qArray = new Array();
    qArray[0] = {image:"Images/q1.png"};
    qArray[1] = {image:"Images/q2.png"};
    qArray[2] = {image:"Images/q3.png"};
    qArray[3] = {image:"Images/q4.png"};
    qArray[4] = {image:"Images/q5.png"};

var count = 0;
var question = qArray.splice(count,1);
```

when i use this i get "undefined":

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question.image;
```

and when i use this i get nothing:

```
document.getElementById("question").src = question.image;
```

my html is just a simple div like so:

```
<div id = "question" align = "center">
</div>
```

i need to have the "count" variable because it increments to show the next image for the next question

if anyone could help that would be great

Comment: `document.getElementById("question").src` is incorrect as `<div>` doesn't have a `src` attribute.

Comment: Is this really all code you have? It doesn't make sense that qArray.splice(count,1).image returns undefined if the variable qArray looks like you've shown in this code

Comment: At a glance it appears splicing is unnecessary you could just access the image with its index using question=qArray[count].

Comment: var question = qArray.[count];
document.getElementById("question").src = question.image;          <img src = "" id = "question" align = "center">
</img>i've changed it to this but it's still not showing anything

Comment: @PaddyHallihan It could be that the script is running before the <img> element is loaded and can't access it because it doesn't exist yet. You can make sure it runs after everything is loaded by putting the <script> tags at the end of the body just before the </body> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s3vv/). qArray.splice() doesn't work because it actually removes that element from the array and returns a new array while you were just looking for a specific index in the array (not to mention you just deleted the element you were looking for)

This works. I used a random imgur image to show that it does indeed load.

```
<html><head></head><body>

<img src="" id="question"></img>

<script type="text/javascript">

var qArray = new Array();
    qArray[0] = {image:"http://i.imgur.com/pGpmq.jpg"};
    qArray[1] = {image:"Images/q2.png"};
    qArray[2] = {image:"Images/q3.png"};
    qArray[3] = {image:"Images/q4.png"};
    qArray[4] = {image:"Images/q5.png"};

var count = 0;
var question = qArray[count];

document.getElementById('question').src = question.image;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```